# Formulare (German) vs Forms (English)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am getting an issue running a Microsot Access Database (.accdb).

The application was made by a German colleague (using Ms Access in German language of course), now after I copied into my machine (I am using Ms Access in English language) I am getting the following prompts: "Enter parameters values" (see screenshot).

[image]

It is clear that the program is looking for values like "Auswahl_MinDate" , in the query I replaced all the code from "Formulare" to "Forms" - it has worked however it is still looking for 2 more values starting with Formulare.

I tried to check all the Forms, Query 1 by 1 however could not find significant results.

For example the 'Auswahl_MinDate' is a date picker control, hence I deleted and recreated but still...

Where else this 'Forumulare' could be set ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the Parameters dialog in query design.

Comment: Check SQLview. There, you should be able to see all `Formulare`. Also, if a query uses fields from other queries/tables fields, check also those related queries/fields. And also. even if the rowsource of a form is a *clean* query with no criterias, notice that you can add criterias to controls in a form

Comment: Alternatively, a global search tool: https://www.devhut.net/2017/03/31/great-access-tools-find-and-replace/

Comment: @Andre: the link given in the blog seems broken, by chance do you have a direct link ? I tried to google but could not find a relevant one. Also is this a paid tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find it in query parameters or SQL, it may be hidden in control properties.

Your best bet is probably a global search tool.

**Search For Text** (Free, open source)
https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/1992076

The 2nd post has an .accdb for Access 2016 (the original is .mdb)
You need to register to download the file.

Still available for download, but unfortunately not for purchase is **Find and Replace** by Rick Fisher (Shareware)
http://www.rickworld.com/download.html

V 9.00k also works for Access 2016 / 365.
I don't remember if it stops working after 30 days or just keeps nagging.

Comment: This tool is really helpful, I found all the entries and changed accordingly and now it works. Thanks Andre!